# Can you help me transpose this data from rows into columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

**Sample Input**:

| YearNum | WeekNum | DayNum | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 1 | 28.40 |
| 2023 | 1 | 3 | 33.09 |
| 2023 | 1 | 4 | 35.20 |
| 2023 | 1 | 5 | 32.77 |
| 2023 | 1 | 6 | 37.15 |
| 2023 | 1 | 7 | 40.18 |
| 2023 | 2 | 1 | 29.43 |
| 2023 | 2 | 3 | 19.43 |
| 2023 | 2 | 4 | 36.62 |
| 2023 | 2 | 5 | 34.81 |
| 2023 | 2 | 6 | 38.50 |
| 2023 | 2 | 7 | 41.98 |
| 2023 | 3 | 1 | 29.09 |
| 2023 | 3 | 3 | 28.63 |
| 2023 | 3 | 4 | 41.59 |

I'm attempting to write sql to transpose the records in the sample input table to obtain the final product as shown in the following output.

**Expected Output**:

| YearNum | WeekNum | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | Total_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 28.40 | 0.0 | 33.09 | 35.20 | 32.77 | 37.15 | 40.18 | 206.79 |
| 2023 | 2 | 29.43 | 0.0 | 19.43 | 36.62 | 34.81 | 38.50 | 41.98 | 200.77 |
| 2023 | 3 | 29.09 | 0.0 | 28.63 | 41.59 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 99.31 |

Notice that the OUTPUT has all 7 days (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) even when the INPUT doesn't have that info.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like standard pivot. Have you checked how it works in SQL Server and actually tried something?

Just to be that guy, here's a non-pivot solution for you:

```sql
select YearNum, weeknum
,   sum(case when DayNum = 1 then hours else 0 end) AS [1]
 ,  sum(case when DayNum = 2 then hours else 0 end) AS [2]
 ,  sum(case when DayNum = 3 then hours else 0 end) AS [3]
 ,  sum(case when DayNum = 4 then hours else 0 end) AS [4]
 ,  sum(case when DayNum = 5 then hours else 0 end) AS [5]
 ,  sum(case when DayNum = 6 then hours else 0 end) AS [6]
 ,  sum(case when DayNum = 7 then hours else 0 end) AS [7]
 ,  sum(hours) AS Hours
from yoursaletable t
group by yearnum, weeknum
```